# Firebase - filter on range

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase on Android platform. I have a question, is it possible to build query with filter based on values range? 
I see that there are methods like `startAt()` and `endAt()`, but I don't see anything to build filter on values range. I saw that iOS have something like `queryStartingAtValue` etc. (see range queries here: [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries)).

Is this possible to do something like that on Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `startAt()` and `endAt()` to specify a range (inclusive the given values):

```
Query query = ref.orderByKey().startAt("0").endAt("5");
```

The [Android docs also cover those range queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries).